# Filter azure cli output based on nested array values with jmespath

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to filter the output from the following Azure CLI command based on the `artifacts[].alias` value.

**Command**

```sh
az pipelines release definition list --artifact-type build
```

**Output (simplified)**

```json
[
    {
        "artifacts": [
            {
                "alias": "alias_with_suffix",
                "definitionReference": {
                    "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                        "id": "False",
                        "name": "False"
                    }
                },
                "type": "Build"
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2021-06-16T15:15:07.620000+00:00",
        "id": 88,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "modifiedOn": "2021-09-15T10:39:14.257000+00:00",
        "revision": 5
    },
    {
        "artifacts": [
            {
                "alias": "alias",
                "definitionReference": {
                    "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                        "id": "False",
                        "name": "False"
                    }
                },
                "type": "Build"
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2021-06-16T15:15:07.620000+00:00",
        "id": 88,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "modifiedOn": "2021-09-15T10:39:14.257000+00:00",
        "revision": 5
    },
    {
        "artifacts": null,
        "createdOn": "2021-06-16T15:15:07.620000+00:00",
        "id": 88,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "modifiedOn": "2021-09-15T10:39:14.257000+00:00",
        "revision": 5
    }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
    {
        "artifacts": [
            {
                "alias": "alias_with_suffix",
                "definitionReference": {
                    "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                        "id": "False",
                        "name": "False"
                    }
                },
                "type": "Build"
            }
        ],
        "createdOn": "2021-06-16T15:15:07.620000+00:00",
        "id": 88,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "modifiedOn": "2021-09-15T10:39:14.257000+00:00",
        "revision": 5
    }
]
```

So far i have tried the following:

- ```sh
  az pipelines release definition list --artifact-type build --query "[artifacts[?ends_with(alias, '_suffix')]]"
  ```
- ```sh
  az pipelines release definition list --artifact-type build --query "[].[artifacts[?ends_with(alias, '_suffix')]]"
  ```
- ```sh
  az pipelines release definition list --artifact-type build --query "[].artifacts[?ends_with(alias, '_suffix')]"
  ```

I've also tried to use something like `[*].....` or pipe results between commands like `[] | [].....` (with or without the `*`) but I always get something like `[null]` or some output with a list of `null` mixed with valid values.

Comment: What do you expect as a result? `[].artifacts[?ends_with(alias, '_suffix')]` is the right syntax.

Comment: I expect to get the full output list, not only the artifatcs part. I want everything which artifacts.alias contains _suffix.

Comment: Then you'll have to provide enough data (output) so we can reproduce your issue and give you clues, as it is currently written, you have your solution already.

Comment: I have added a better Output example and also an Expected Output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you will have to have a *"nested"* filter expression, because you are interested in the *"parent"* object based on the fact that a condition in the array of key `artifacts` is true.

So, given the query:

```
[?artifacts[?ends_with(alias, '_suffix')]]
```

You end up, with the JSON you provided as input, with this resulting JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "artifacts": [
      {
        "alias": "alias_with_suffix",
        "definitionReference": {
          "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
            "id": "False",
            "name": "False"
          }
        },
        "type": "Build"
      }
    ],
    "createdOn": "2021-06-16T15:15:07.620000+00:00",
    "id": 88,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "modifiedOn": "2021-09-15T10:39:14.257000+00:00",
    "revision": 5
  }
]
```